# More than two SPI devices on an Arm board that supports only two?

Tags: linux-device-driver, spi

The Arm processor on one of our boards has an spi port with two chip select lines.
It is mentioned in the processor's datasheet that it can control upto two spi devices.

Is it possible to use a GPIO as a slave select for an additional spi device?
How to modify the existing libraries/device drivers to support this change?

So far i've found a file in the kernel's source which contains the addresses of SPI port pins. Can anyone plz tell in which direction should i proceed?

Comment: Depending on the slave, you can daisy chain or for simple applications just add some gates to your GPIO+SS that split the SS into two, one that can go low if GPIO is high and one that can go low if GPIO is low (ie SS1=GPIO OR SS, SS2=(!GPIO) OR SS) If your application manages pulling GPIO high/low depending on the slave you want to talk to, you may not need any kernel changes.

Comment: You can, but it will be tricky if the spi peripheral was auto-asserting the selects, instead of the driver asserting them as GPIOs.   To use assert your extension ones as GPIOs you would have to make it assert none of the built-ins (or run all of them as GPIOs) also you may need to be careful of timing since SPI tends to be a mildly queued operation - but here you will have to manually de-assert the selects.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i dont want to drive the GPIOs from the user application. I want the spi driver to treat a GPIO pin as one of the built in Slave Selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what processor it is.  You have three possibilities.

1. If the processor has an `i/o mux` capabilities, turn off the SPI chip select functionality.  The SPI controller will think it has asserted the line, but it won't go external.
2. Don't connect one SPI chip select.  Use a pull-up/down for ESD protection.
3. Multiplex the `chip select` as  per [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson)

In first two cases, connect `GPIO`s to the additional device's chip select.  Toggle the `GPIO` manually before running `spi_write()`, etc.  This will allow the `SPI` controller to transfer at higher rates than are possible with **bit banging** and is a better system design.  Ie, lower power consumption, lower CPU use, faster data rates, etc.  If the peripheral is just for setup/boot, then the **bit banging** makes sense for simplicity.  However, if your main operation depends on the SPI bus, you could consider this solution.

If only one peripheral needs the SPI for setup **AND** you have the `i/o mux`, you can disable the chip select functionality during setup, using a GPIO to select the *setup* peripheral and then re-enable the `spi chip select` during *standard* system operation for the other peripheral.

Using a `GPIO` doesn't require user space intervention.  Drivers can provide `call backs` to set the GPIO when in use, so `SPI` commands can be buffered/queued and these solutions still work.  For instance, the [IMX `SPI` driver](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=drivers/spi/spi-imx.c;hb=HEAD) supports GPIO toggle by passing a negative chip select number to denote a GPIO id.

**Note:** Some SPI devices may require the `chip select` to toggle between `words`; what ever a `word` is for the device.  Some controller may leave the `chip select` asserted when transferring multiple words.  You need to get this right if you use a GPIO to manually select devices.  I am sure some standard defines this, but definitely some device don't follow the standard.

**Addendum:** Most drivers support a `GPIO` chip select; via a negative chip select value.  They will call Linux `GPIO` functions.  Write a `GPIO` handler that does the de-multiplexing.  No need to alter the `SPI` drivers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough pins, you can bitbang the whole SPI protocol and use as many CS as you need.

Comment: +1 I believe Linux already has a **bit bang** driver, only the `GPIOs` need to be defined to use it.